# No Context Menu And Icon Overlays on Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10, tortoisegit

I installed Git for Windows 64bit and Tortoise 64bits but after that I can't access the context menu and the overlays icons doesn't work too.
Anyone have a solution for this issue?

I tried reinstall, checked regedit (Computador\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers) and many others options but i had not success.

my system informations:

- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview - 10.0.21286 Compilação 21286
- Git-2.30.0.2-64-bit
- TortoiseGit-2.11.0.0-64bit

Comment: Do you see TortoiseGit on the context menu when you press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while opening the context menu on a folder?

Comment: unfortunately not. Nothing happens. Just "Git GUI Here" and "Git Bash Here"

Comment: I found a new issue. Inside the SQL Server Management Studio in "Open File" dialog the Context Menu and Overlays Icons worked.

Comment: have you logged off and on again?

Comment: yes... many times